# Google Compute Engine CPU Quotas

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

How do I find out about the current Google Compute Engine CPU quotas for my project at a particular data center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out the quota for CPUs please follow these instructions:

1. Go to the [Quota Increase page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) in the Google Cloud Platform Console.
2. Expand the Quota type dropdown menu and select All quotas.
3. Expand the Metric dropdown menu.
4. Click on None to hide all quotas and then type CPUs in the search box to search for CPUs quota.
5. Select CPUs from the results list.
6. You should be able to see all Google Compute Engine CPU quotas for all region